# How to get OriginalRequest from HTTP Request in ServerWebExchange

Tags: spring, kotlin, httprequest, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using Spring Cloud Gateway, and am trying to figure out how to get the "OriginalRequest" from the ServerWebExchange Request (so that I can use the URI).

I can see the OriginalRequest in the IntelliJ debugger (please see screenshot below).  The issue that I am having is that it does not appear to be a public field (please see the last screenshot).

Do you know how I can access the OriginalRequest? Thanks a lot!

[image: IntelliJ debugger Picture]
[image: What is available from the Object]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the URI for the OriginalRequest from the ServerWebExchange by doing the following:

`serverWebExchange.getAttribute<LinkedHashSet<URI?>?>(ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_ORIGINAL_REQUEST_URL_ATTR)?.firstOrNull()`

Credit to this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/ptaylor/311d0442ffd903f4725182031defd615) for showing me how to get it in Java:

`LinkedHashSet<URI> attr = serverWebExchange.getAttribute(ServerWebExchangeUtils.GATEWAY_ORIGINAL_REQUEST_URL_ATTR);`